# Why is built-in call recording such a rare feature on Android devices?

Tags: calls, call-recording

As the title says.
I find it really weird to see it this way, as I know the OS itself do support it.
Even Nexus devices don't have it built in.

On some Android devices, you would even need to root them in order to have call recording.

I know the laws of call recording are different between countries, but still, how could some devices (and even Nokia devices) have this feature, while most Android devices don't?

Comment: I think it's just because it's illegal in some countries. But it's Android, you can do everything with root :)

Comment: @SuperThomasLab But still, it's available on some Android devices yet not on most, and it's available even on WP devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it mostly has to do with both of the following:

1. A lack of demand for the feature. While a small minority of users may want this feature, most "normal" users probably never even think about it.
2. The laws in the US regarding recording phone calls are relatively complex. They usually vary from state to state ([source](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/recording-phone-calls-and-conversations)). Companies probably do not want to expose themselves to additional liability.

If #1 was to change so that a sizable number of people want this feature, then a company would be more likely to put the effort in to make sure that the feature works legally.

Comment: I think Asus phones, which aren't that popular, have this feature built in. How can they do it, while others don't?

Comment: I am not familiar with many ASUS phones, but maybe ASUS decided their target market may want this feature while others decided not enough of their customers care. While the demographics ASUS is selling to are probably similar to other companies, ASUS may make internal decisions differently than other companies.